# .on(“click”, function() not working when use within ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: javascript, c#, function

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#LkForgot').on('click', function (e) {
                alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The above code doesn't work. When I click on #LkForgot within ContentPlaceHolder, it doesn't alert

This is the my masterpage:

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title>viber bulk sender</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/autosize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/custombox.min.css">
        <script src="script/custombox.min.js"></script>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </head>

<body style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 12px;">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="main register relative" style="min-height: 100%; margin: 0; text-align: center;">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

This is the script within the Content control:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/custombox.min.css">
    <script src="script/custombox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/autosize.min.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#LkForgot').on('click', function (e) {
                Custombox.open({
                    target: '#ddd',
                    effect: 'fadein'
                });
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LkForgot" runat="server">Forgot Password</asp:LinkButton>
    <div id="ddd">
        adsfasdfasd
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Read [ask] carefully.

Comment: in you linkbutton use attribute  ClientIDMode as static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modify the source path like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js")%>' ></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Register your control event like:

```
$('[id$=LkForgot]').on('click', function (e) {
            Custombox.open({
                target: '#ddd',
                effect: 'fadein'
            });
            e.preventDefault();
 });
```

Or

use ClientIDMode as static in linkbutton.

Answer (score 0):

When you put something inside ContentPlaceHolder, its id will be changed when rendered to client's browser.

So you have to use `.class` for this because you are using `div`.

If there are any server controls, you can use following code to get clientside id.

```
$("#<%=ServerControl1.ClientID%>").click(function(){
    //CODE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add jquery file like this**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js")%>' ></script>

     then 
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#<%=LkForgot.ClientID%>").click(function(){
        //CODE
    });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#<%=LkForgot.ClientID%>").click(function(){
        //CODE
    });
```

OR

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

$("#<%=LkForgot.ClientID%>").click(function(){
        //CODE
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be part of your other answer? You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34413658/edit) posts. And when you're at it instead of *try this* a little bit more explanation would be helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score -2):

You call the function with the class name. because the ids are changes when page created. **OR** you can inspect the page html and get the right id of the element. or